# Is it permissible to refuse halal food?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I heard a friend say that as Muslims we should eat everything that has been made halal for us and if we don't then we will be questioned on the last day. I am specifically referring to rabbit meat here: I have never tasted it nor do I intend to, but is my refusal to eat it considered a sin on my part?

Comment: +1 for clear formulation of question.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to believe that you're obliged to eat anything just because it's *halal*, as long as you don't refuse it *because* you think it's unlawful (it's not).

There is a relevant hadith wherein some people offered lizard meat to the prophet and he refused it: Not because it was unlawful, only because he felt he would not like it as it was not a customary dish among his people.